# Tag Page - clear up all the numbers!

Tags: discussion, tags, usability

I have just got the Taxonomist badge and whilst trying to work out what for, I took a look at the tags status page.

This page has numbers everywhere and is quite hard to understand. ([example link](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=windows-7&sort=stats&pagesize=50))

The colors made me feel a bit weird starting at it for a while trying to figure out what the first column meant, but then I looked in the source code and I could see that it is called "Total Score".

I see that it is a tool tip that says it, however, it is not at all obvious. I have no suggestion on how to improve this, but I just thought it needs to be said!

[image]

Comment: It was already said. The solution was reading the tooltips. What part of the toolstips you don't understand?

Comment: Because it is not at all obvious that reading the tool tips is what you have to do! They are not hyperlinks and it is by no means obvious that you have to hover to find out what they are... infact, I only found out that there is tooltips after I looked in the source code for the name!

Comment: That means you do not want that the relevant information is hidden by the tooltips (or better: must be revealed by using them). Then it is not a dupe.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a crazy idea - how about putting the column titles at the *top of the columns*? Having "Total score" and "N answers" at the top of the columns would make the static version of the page instantly comprehensible.

I am no UI expert, but I do know this page has confused me in the past. IMO tooltips should be for helpful extra information, not for fundamental descriptions of values.

Answer (score 0):

Just mouse over the numbers and it explains what they are. This is true of most UI in any stack overflow family site...

Comment: I said this in the comments with John Smithers - Whilst I understand now - hovering over something is not the first thing I would generally try and I only discovered it was a hover over after looking at the source code. Not saying it doesn't work - but it really isn't obvious.

Comment: I think a *good* interface can be understood at the first glance. If you first have to move the mouse over something plus even wait for a tooltip - that's about as bad as it can get.